# Find $\angle x$ in the figure if ABCD is a rhombus, BEC is equilateral and

Tags: geometry

For reference: Find $\angle~ x$ in the figure if ABCD is a rhombus, BEC is equilateral and $\measuredangle BCT = 2m\measuredangle BAE$ (answer: $60^\circ$)

original figure:
[image]

My progress:

$ABCD : square\\
ABC: \triangle equilateral \implies \theta = 30^\circ\\
\measuredangle BET = 60^\circ$

still missing an equation
[image]

I couldn't draw with the "rhombus" itself, only with the particular case of a square that is a rhombus

Comment: It seems you changed some labels from original diagram. You labelled the old C as E and the old E as C. This should be fixed in your new diagram, and in the section "My progress:".

Comment: @coffeemath...thanks for the alert..I've corrected it

Comment: $CE=DE=ET$ and $\angle TED=60$, so $\triangle ETD$ is equilateral

Comment: $\measuredangle BCT = 2m\measuredangle BAE$... What is $m$?

Comment: @petaarantes I see no change here. Please check at your end to make sure labels all correspond. [Maybe it just takes time for your edits to "go through the system" to other viewers.]

Comment: Depending on whether $CD$ and $CE$ are collinear or not, the figure could either be an isosceles trapezoid (as it appears to be in the first figure) or a pentagon (as it appears to be in the second figure).

Comment: @SayanDutta... m = MEASUREMENT

Comment: @coffeemath  see now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$ABCD$ is a rhombus and $\triangle BCE$ is equilateral.
Also, $\angle BCT = 2 \angle BAE$.

Please note position of point $T$ on $AE$ changes as the angles of rhombus change. When $D, C, E$ are collinear (the acute angle of rhombus being $60^\circ$), $T$ falls on vertex $A$. I have shown above the construct for acute angle of rhombus being greater than $60^\circ$. What you drew (a square) is a specific case. When acute angle of rhombus is less than $60^\circ$, point $T$ is outside rhombus on $EA$ extend such that $\angle BCT = 2 \angle BAE$. See a diagram showing this construct at the end of the answer.

---

Now coming to the solution,

Say, $\angle ABC = \theta$ then $\angle ABE = 60^\circ + \theta$. $\angle BAE = \angle BEA = 60^\circ - \frac{\theta}{2}, \angle AEC = \frac{\theta}{2}$

$\angle BCT = 2 \angle BAE = 120^\circ - \theta, \angle ECT = 180^\circ - \theta$

So, $\angle CTE = \frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\triangle ECT$ is isosceles and $CT = EC = CD$.

$\angle DCT = \angle BCD - \angle BCT = 60^\circ$

That concludes $\triangle DCT$ is equilateral and hence, $\angle CTD = 60^\circ$

---

A construct with $\angle BCT = 2 \angle BAE$ and $\angle ABC \lt 60^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: @Math..excellent grateful

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hints: Triangle ABE is isosceles so:

$\angle BAE=\angle BEA=\frac{\angle BCT}2$

that is T is on the circle center at C, so $TC=BC=CD$

Now if you proove $TD=TC$ then $x=60^o$